# Loopback4 hasMany, keyFrom can be array?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I am trying to use hasMany relationship in loopback. I have problem while using it. I have an array, which is contains to ids from target model and I want to find all elements belongs to that array and I want to list them. How can I do it?

```
  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
  })
  exampleArray?: string[];

  @hasMany(() => MainComponent, {keyFrom: 'exampleArray', keyTo: 'id'})
  mainComponent: MainComponent[];
```

Answer (score 1):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

> I have an array, which is contains to ids from target model

LoopBack's `hasMany` relation uses a foreign key on the target model instance to establish the relation. For example, if a `Category` has many `Product` models, then `Product` model must have a property linking it back to the owning category - this is typically `categoryId`.

IIUC your domain model, you want the source model (`Category`) to store the list of target model ids (`Product.id`) that belong to this category. In LoopBack, we call such relation type `referencesMany`.

LoopBack 4 does not implement `referencesMany` relation yet, please join the discussion in GitHub issue [loopback-next#2488](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2488) or at least upvote  the issue to let us know about your interest.

Comment: FWIW and IIUC this answer was ASAP :P